# How to use state in component through connect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using reactjs and redux to build my simple app. I follow some tutorial and i get an error.

My connect

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
     console.log(state) // WHAT IS FORMAT? {....}
     return {
          messages: state.messages // i don't know state contain messsages key
     }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

and MyComponent

```
const MyComponent= ({messages}) => (
        <ul>
            {messages.map(message => (
                <Child
                    key={message.id}
                    {...message}
                />
            ))}
        </ul>
)
```

I create my store by

```
createStore(
        reducer, applyMiddleware(myMiddleware())
    );
```

But i don't know `state` format. it is object of some key ? I don't find any define `state` format in tut, and i get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

How to understand and fix that.

Comment: did you create a reducer function which contains the `message` props?

Comment: @Thinker `key` of state is reducer ?

Comment: can you share the reducer code?

Comment: @Thinker Maybe, key in `state` object is contain by list reducers example combineReducers({ messages, hello }); then state will contain two key of that, I just tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state parameter provided to connect is an object that contains the current redux state. Anything you’ve created using your reducers will be available here.

See https://redux.js.org/api/store#getState for more information.

In your case you likely haven’t set up any reducers yet, and so the messages store object isn’t yet populated. If you complete the tutorial it will take you through the setup.

Comment: Seem, key in `state` object is contain by list `reducers` example combineReducers({
 messages, hello
}); then `state` will contain two key of that?

Comment: Correct, any reducers you specify will be available in the state object.